# Timed popup page adjusted by language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, popup

I am working on a multilingual website that was built with Drupal (PHP) and was asked by my boss to create a pop up page as following:

1) The pop up page should appear 60 seconds (or less) after the page has been uploaded by a user.
2) The pop up page should be fixed into a certain size (I still don't know the exact width and length).
3) The page should appear in the language of the user - This one shouldn't be that tricky since the page is already fixed to the users language through the URL - Suppose it's an Italian user, the URL will be it.mywebsite.com, if it's a French user, the URL will be fr.mywebsite.com and so on.

I am quite novice with JavaScript and jQuery and would appreciate some help here. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

make site trigger this after_upload function after upload, you can do it by php or js

```
function after_upload("<?php echo $site_lang; ?>"){
setTimeout(function() {popupitup(language);},4500);}

function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(language+'.popup.html','name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
```

create a seperate page for each language and thats it

Comment: I think I understood, but where to I set the time for 60 seconds?

Comment: Set to 60000 for 60 seconds. 1 second = 1000 miliseconds.